# zip file with php - exclude the folder

Tags: php

I have one zip function, and i want each file inside FOLDER to zip

So, the path is:

public_html/form/FOLDER/file_to_zip.xml

As you can see in the code bellow, the $files_to_zip array has the "FOLDER/file_to_zip.xml" path and whenever it zips, also zips the folder, i only want the file to get zipped.

What can i do here?

```
function create_zip($files = array(),$destination = '',$overwrite = true) {

    $valid_files = array();
    if(is_array($files)) {
        foreach($files as $file) {
            if(file_exists($file)) {
                $valid_files[] = $file;
            }
        }
    }
    if(count($valid_files)) {
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        if($zip->open($destination,$overwrite ? ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE : ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== true) {
            return false;
        }
        foreach($valid_files as $file) {
            $zip->addFile($file,$file);
        }

        $zip->close();

        return file_exists($destination);
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

$loja=$_GET['loja'];

$connect = new MySQL('localhost','iloja_phc','sexparade');
$connect->Database('iloja_phc');
$posts = $connect->Fetch('ipad');

if ($posts && mysql_num_rows($posts) > 0) {
     echo "Nome  -  ID  -  Email:<BR>";
     while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($posts)) {
    $files_to_zip = array($loja.'/CL'.$record['rand'].'.xml');
    $result = create_zip($files_to_zip,'CL'.$record['rand'].'.zip');
         echo "<a href='/formulario/CL".$record['rand'].".zip'>".$record['nome']."</a> - ".$record['id']." - EMAIL: ".$record['email']."</br>";
     }
} else {
     echo "Erro! Algo correu mal...";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're calling

```
$zip->addFile($file,$file);
```

the first parameter is the path to the file, and the second is the "localname". If you remove the folder from the second parameter you'll get what you need.

Example:

```
$zip->addFile("foo/bar.txt","bar.txt);
```

For your particular case, I think this should work:

```
$zip->addFile($file, basename($file));
```

Source: PHP manual comments http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php