# How to exclude folder(s) from ZIP file generation using php?

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I found a [great solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914750/how-to-zip-a-whole-folder-using-php/4914785#4914785) on how to ZIP folders and files on my server, but how do I make the script exclude the folder /archiv and all of its subfolders?

```
$backup_file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/archiv/system/system_' . date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") . '.zip';

$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open($backup_file, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
);

foreach ($files as $name => $file)
{
    if($file == 'archiv'){
        continue;
    }else{
        // Skip directories (they would be added automatically)
        if (!$file->isDir()){
            $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
            $relativePath = substr($filePath, strlen($rootPath) + 1);
            $zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);
        }
    }
}

$zip->close();
```

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: What have you tried so far? An btw, why don't you check your answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30076866/171318 first before you ask another question?

Comment: @hek2mgl it's in the code: if($file == 'archiv'){continue;}else{...}

Comment: And what is not working for you?

Comment: The script includes the archiv folder in the ZIP file. It should ignore it!

Comment: You can simply check whether `$file->getRealPath()` starts with the path to the `archive` folder. In that case ignore them.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305374/zip-file-with-php-exclude-the-folder

Comment: Hello Richard Tinkler. Did you find a solution on how to exclude folder from the archive?